# Send local push notifications from Flutter calendar widget

Tags: flutter, notifications, calendar

I am trying to find a way to send the user a notification that a deadline is coming up for an event that has been scheduled in a calendar widget in Flutter.

Is there a way to do this in the table_calendar widget or is there another widget that will do this?

For example, when a user sets a day and time in the calendar to call a client or something like this, is there a way to send a local notification to the user in the app that they need to call the client in 10 minutes? I have not been able to find anything for this.

Right now, I am using the table_calendar widget in my flutter app but I can change if there is a different app that provides this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **flutter_local_notification** package

[Flutter Local Notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Also use this method of table_calender.

```
selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
  return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
},
```

based on this outcome call to local notification in app